# Big Endian Format to Decimal Coversion

Tags: javascript

**How to covert the big Endian Format to Decimal Format in javascript ?**

*some big Endian Format Data:*

```
{   "wh": "0:0:0:0:0:251:132:0",
    "vry": "0:0:27:84",
    "vyb": "0:0:0:0",
    "vbr": "67:114:33:235",
    "vrn": "67:114:28:164",
    "vyn": "0:0:0:0",
    "vbn": "0:0:0:0",
    "ir": "0:0:0:0",
    "iy": "0:0:0:0",
    "ib": "0:0:0:0",
    "kva":"66:158:57:154",
    "pfr":"63:116:4:72",
    "var":"0:0:0:0:136:28:56:100",
    "me": "vk"
}
```

*expected value:Data*

```
  { wh: 16.483328,
    vry: 0,
    vyb: 0,
    vbr: 242,
    vrn: 242,
    vyn: 0,
    vbn: 0,
    ir: 0,
    iy: 0,
    ib: 0,
    kva: 79,
    pfr: 0.953125,
    var: 2283.55082 }
```

Comment: Your question looks like a bunch of random characters in my opinion. Please explain the logic behind `0:0:0:0:0:251:132:0` ==> `16.483328`, and `0:0:27:84` ==> `0`.

Comment: I'm actually searching for the logic as well. I just got this problem with the expected solution but really I am unable to figure out how is this possible.

Comment: So what makes you think that the input format is Big Endian?

Comment: Note that two different inputs (`vbr` and `vrn`) are mapped to the same output value `242`. I suggest that you check the source of that problem.

Comment: I got it from somewhere as a problem to be solved that is the reason I am asking for help here.